# gVim Dynamically Change Font Based on Window Size

Tags: vim

I'm running gVim 7.3 on a GNU/Linux machine.  I'm wondering if there is a way to change the font automatically based on the size of the window.  I'm relatively new to Vim, so I'm not terrible familiar with it.

My situation is this: I'm using DejaVu Sans Mono 12 for my default font, but sometimes I like to switch down to Terminus 9 when I want to shrink the Vim window down to look at something on my screen while I type.  (You know, for those of us with tiny laptop screens that don't want to keep switching between workspaces...!)

So I'm wondering if this behaviour can happen automatically with a command in the .vimrc file if I shrink the default window size down small enough so that Vim will automatically adjust the font.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vim fires the `VimResized` event when its window size is changed. You can write an autocmd that adapts the font (`'guifont'`) then. Here's an example that only considers `'columns'` (not '`lines'`), and has a hard-coded font name:

```
function! FontChangeOnResize()
    if &columns > 80
        set guifont=Lucida_Console:h14
    elseif &columns > 60
        set guifont=Lucida_Console:h12
    elseif &columns > 40
        set guifont=Lucida_Console:h10
    elseif &columns > 20
        set guifont=Lucida_Console:h8
    else
        set guifont=Lucida_Console:h6
    endif
endfunction
autocmd VimResized * call FontChangeOnResize()
```